# android drawables are colored automatically with color primary and it will not change

Tags: android, colors, background-color, drawable

when i change the background of any View to some drawable, it is colored with color primary (in my case #FF6200EE), and it won't change.

for example, when i change a background of a button, the background color sets automatically to color primary and it won't change even after setting backgroudTint

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"/>
```

here is the rectangle.XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle">
<size android:width="40dp" android:height="40dp" />
<solid android:color="@color/white"/>
</shape>
```

EDIT: here is the whole main xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TourGuide.AppBarOverlay">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and here is themes.xml file :

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.TourGuide" 
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">? 
    attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="Theme.TourGuide.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.TourGuide.AppBarOverlay" 
parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="Theme.TourGuide.PopupOverlay" 
parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

Comment: I just added your rectangle.xml to my project and tried it with a button and everything worked great. Except you didn't have closing tag </shape> in your XML. But this isn't the issue. Please check that you don't have some overlapping layouts with primary color or if you are changing it programmatically, or maybe even check your theme if there you added any attribute that could do this.

Comment: @SlothCoding thank you, i just forget to copy the closing tag, thank you for your suggestions, i suspect it is the third one, when i checked the styles in the values.XML i got really confused, so any help would be more than welcome

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your styles.xml and your whole XML where button is created.

Comment: @SlothCoding in my project a styles.xml file wasn't generated, though i find the styles in the themes.XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are using MaterialComponents Theme and I suggest that you use Material Components too. Instead of Button, you can use:

```
com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
```

More about MaterialComponents and Material Themes you can find here: https://material.io/components?platform=android

To change the color of your Button or MaterialButton you need to use:

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/somecolor"
```

instead of:

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/somecolor"
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: thank you very much it worked, one last thing, i wonder why you recommended MaterialButton instead of Button

Comment: It has more attributes I think and it is more compatible with MaterialComponents Themes. Check the link I gave you, you have everything in there, and it is by the "standards" on how to create an app, which dimensions to take, and other stuff.

Comment: ok, i will check that, thank you very for your help